# Where does the helix $r(t) =(\cos(\pi t), \sin(\pi t), t)$ intersect the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Where does the helix $r(t) = (\cos (\pi t), \sin (\pi t), t)$ intersect the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$?

What is the angle of intersection between the helix and the paraboloid?

I have found the derivative of $r(t) = r'(t) = (-\pi \sin (πt), \pi \cos(πt), 1)$

I'm not sure how to incorporate this with the given equation of the paraboloid or to find any values from this.

Comment: Write down the parametric equation defining the paraboloid, then it is a matter of setting the vectors equal

Comment: So would that be <2x, 2y, -1>?

Comment: Simply substitute $r(t)$ into $z=x^2+y^2$ and solve for $t$.

Comment: Ok, I got my values, but how do I find the angle of intersection?

Comment: The tangent plane of the paraboloid at $(x_1,y_1)$ is $z_1 z=2(x_1 x+y_1 y)$

Comment: By the way for future reference a parametric equation for a surface defined by $z = f(x,y)$ can be given by $\vec{r}(x,y) = x \hat{i} + y \hat{j} + f(x,y) \hat{k} $ (this can be done also for if x or y is a function of the remaining variables). To find the angle of intersection you find the normal vector to the surface at the point of contact, and use the tangent vector of the curve intersecting the surface at the point of contact in the definition of the dot product as $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = |a||b| \cos{\theta}$